# If condition is not executing

Tags: java, function, if-statement, libgdx, intersection

I am trying to figure out if my object is being hit, with a little lenience. But it is not working. Here is my **code:**

```
public boolean isClicked(float x) {

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched() && Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() >= this.getY() && Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() <= this.getY() + this.getHeight() && this.getWidth() >= Gdx.input.getX() && x < this.getY() + this.getHeight() * 1.2f && x > this.getY() - this.getHeight() * .2f) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use condition in this way and use bracket for multiple condition :

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched() && ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) >= this.getY()) && ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) <= (this.getY() + this.getHeight())) && (this.getWidth() >= Gdx.input.getX()) && (x < ((this.getY() + this.getHeight()) * 1.2f)) && (x > ((this.getY() - this.getHeight()) * .2f))) {
      return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try and format long lines for readability and use parenthesis.

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched() 
    && (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) >= this.getY() 
    && (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) <= (this.getY() + this.getHeight()) 
    && this.getWidth() >= Gdx.input.getX() 
    && x < (this.getY() + this.getHeight() * 1.2f )
    && x > (this.getY() - this.getHeight() * .2f ) 
   ) {
    return true;
}
```

This also lets you comment out the beginning of any of the intermediate lines (eg. using //) to isolate the problem.